# How to completely remove TextArea Vertical ScrollBar

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, scrollbar

I'm trying to remove the TextArea Vertical ScrollBar. The TextArea auto increments its height without displaying the vertical ScrollBar, but it (vertical ScrollBar) re-appears after five lines of typing. How can I completely remove it?

```
public class TextAreaAutoResizable {

    private final Text textHolder = new Text();
    private double oldHeight = 0;

    public void resize(TextArea textArea) {
        textArea.setPrefSize(200, 40);
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        textHolder.textProperty().bind(textArea.textProperty());
        textHolder.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable, Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {
                if (oldHeight != newValue.getHeight()) {
                    System.out.println("newValue = " + newValue.getHeight());
                    oldHeight = newValue.getHeight();
                    textArea.setPrefHeight(textHolder.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() + 20); // +20 is for paddings
                }
            }
        });

        textHolder.setWrappingWidth(textArea.getWidth() - 10);
    }
}
```